# Cannot select option in capybara

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, capybara

I have a problem selecting option from the dropdown.

The HTML is this:

```
<div unselectable="on" class="k-widget k-multiselect k-header" style="" title="">
  <div unselectable="on" class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap">
    <ul class="k-reset" unselectable="on" role="listbox"></ul>
    <input style="width: 25px" class="k-input k-readonly" accesskey="" autocomplete="off" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="28dfc7ec-69a2-4a95-ba29-1f94e899c7e3">
    <span class="k-icon k-loading k-loading-hidden"></span>
  </div>
  <div data-bind="source: getTreeValues, value: selectedCrmAttributes.DYN_" data-text-field="name_i18n" data-value-field="attributeId" data-value-primitive="false" data-auto-bind="true" data-role="interestselect" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
    <option value="DYN_#76ed2b3f-4d64-4d07-8ba7-ab6f133e0c70">one.csv</option>
    <option value="DYN_#6f914af1-ba58-4c40-99fe-e874bdf9c47b">two.csv</option>
    <option value="DYN_#4cd908d0-6c61-4a15-84e7-f113aa7a8ed4">three.csv</option>
    <option value="DYN_#c137cfad-81af-4164-90b1-a518a7595baa">four.csv</option>
   </div>
   <span style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-stretch: normal; font-style: normal; font-weight: 300; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none; line-height: 17.0333px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; top: -3333px; left: -3333px;"></span>
</div>
```

I have tried to select the option by this way

```
And(/^selecting (.*) from (.*)$/) do |item, selection|
  find('.dgr-dimensions-row', :text=>selection).find('.k-widget.k-multiselect.k-header').click
  #expect(page).to have_content(item) -> returns true
  select(item)
end
```

Where the item is the option i want to select and selection is filter from where I want to select the item.

Example: If I have a filter File and the options are one, two, three, four. 
Then the selection is **File** and the item is **one** for example.

I'm using

```
cucumber 2.1.0
ruby 2.1.6
nokogiri 1.6.6.2
capybara 2.4.4
selenium-webdriver 2.47.1
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDITED**

I would like to select the option by text, that the ruby step can be reusable. I have many similar fields like this one and it would be useful if I can reuse the same step.

Picture: [image]

**EDITED 2**

```
<ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-live="polite" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox" style="overflow: auto; height: auto;">
  <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-focused" data-offset-index="0" id="96c13cd6-8365-4e73-a134-6395988822f7">one.csv</li>
  <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="1">two.csv</li>
  <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="2">three.csv</li>
  <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="3">four.csv</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should using jquery to click. example: `evaluate_javascript("query")`

Comment: Do you want to select one of the 4 option values right? Depending from what? In general, to select an option, you can simply do `find("the css selector or the xpath of the option you want to select").select_option` or `find("option[value='the value you want to select']").click`

Comment: I would like to select the item by it's text, because I have similar fields where I could then reuse the step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybaras #select only works with visible html option elements.  The issue here is that you appear to be using a kendo multiselect widget which hides the real option elements ( btw your html is invalid since option elements are only legally allowed to be inside a select, optgroup, or datalist element) and then generates a visible UI using li elements inside a ul.k-list.  From looking at a demo of the kendo multiselect - http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index - it appears the actual ul.k-list element is attached to the page outside of the widget div and therefore a find can't be scoped to the widget, and the ul.list is given an id of "#{id of select hidden in multiselect widget}_list".  Since your html doesn't appear to have an id on the hidden element in the widget there is no way to scope with that either.  Because of all of that, rather than doing `select(item)` you should be able to use

```
find('.k-list li.k-item', text: item).click
```

to click on the element in the dropdown that becomes visible after you click in the header.  It would be better if this find could be scoped to a particular .klist on the page, but hopefully there is only ever one actually visible while you're running the tests.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work work for me. There is no '.klist'. Added a picture to the issue. Maybe it helps.

Comment: We need to know the actual hamlet for the elements you're trying to select.  Right click and inspect on one of the drop down elements - then post that

Comment: Added the HTML to the post.

Comment: Updated my answer to match the new info

Comment: Thanks for answering. Final solution that worked for me was     find('.k-item', :text=>item, :match=>:prefer_exact).click